# Restore original notification icons after uninstalling Xfce

Tags: 12.04, xfce, gnome-classic

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with Gnome Classic environment.

I wanted to try Xfce, so I installed the metapackage xfce4. In the end, I was not convinced so I removed it and came back on Gnome Classic.

The problem is, even though I removed the xfce4 package, it seems a lot of things are still installed, and some modifications have been made.

Some default apps have been changed (Thunar replaced Nautilus as default app), but I could change this.

But how do I revert to the original notification icons instead of these:

[image]

I went into System Settings > Appearance, changed the theme, but the ugly icons are still used for notifications.

P.S.: My question might also be: *how to make sure the metapackage xfce4 has been removed totally?*

Comment: Fixed by removing the xfce4-notifyd package from my system:

    sudo apt-get remove xfce4-notifyd

Answer (score 1):

OP solved the problem by removing the `xfce4-notifyd` by running `sudo apt-get remove xfce4-notifyd`.